# How to get previous non equal salary record in the current row in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

| id | startdate | enddate | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-09-07 | 9999-12-31 | 194000 |
| 1 | 2015-03-01 | 2015-09-06 | 194000 |
| 1 | 2014-04-10 | 2015-02-28 | 194000 |
| 1 | 2014-01-01 | 2014-04-09 | 192000 |
| 1 | 2013-07-31 | 2013-12-31 | 180000 |

This is the table I have, I need to introduce a new column which shows the previous salary for the employee. The challenge that I have is that if the salary is unchanged, it cannot be shown as the previous salary, so in this case the result table would be

| id | startdate | enddate | salary | prevSalary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-09-07 | 9999-12-31 | 194000 | 192000 |
| 1 | 2015-03-01 | 2015-09-06 | 194000 | 192000 |
| 1 | 2014-04-10 | 2015-02-28 | 194000 | 192000 |
| 1 | 2014-01-01 | 2014-04-09 | 192000 | 180000 |
| 1 | 2013-07-31 | 2013-12-31 | 180000 | null (or) 0 |

I tried using the "lag" operator but it doesn't give me the desired output, instead it just picks the salary from the last record which is incorrect.

My query:

```
select *, lag(salary) 
    over(partition by id, order by startdate) as prevSalary 
    from tablename.
```

I also tried partitioning it with "id" and "salary" but I am not able to formulate the proper solution.

Note, there are multiple ids in the table, I am using one id just to give an example. Also the date records are consistent and have no gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you selected the previous salary with `LAG`, in the same partition of salary, there will be the first one that will hold the good result, and the other ones for which salary = lastsalary. You can just apply the `FIRST_VALUE` window function in the very same salary partition, to overwrite the needed lastsalary.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(salary) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate) AS lastsalary
    FROM tab
)
SELECT id, startdate, enddate, salary, 
       FIRST_VALUE(lastsalary) OVER(PARTITION BY id, salary ORDER BY startdate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS lastsalary 
FROM cte
```

**Output**:

| id | startdate | enddate | salary | lastsalary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-09-07 | 9999-12-31 | 194000 | 192000 |
| 1 | 2015-03-01 | 2015-09-06 | 194000 | 192000 |
| 1 | 2014-04-10 | 2015-02-28 | 194000 | 192000 |
| 1 | 2014-01-01 | 2014-04-09 | 192000 | 180000 |
| 1 | 2013-07-31 | 2013-12-31 | 180000 | null |

---

**Edit**: On [ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12705912/ahmed)'s smart suggestion, if salary is not monotonically increasing, and the id happen to have a previously occurring salary, you could need a solution that works in gaps-and-islands setting, for which you would need to rebuild your partitioning as follows:

```
WITH gaps AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate DESC) - 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, salary ORDER BY startdate DESC) grp
    FROM tab
), cte AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(salary) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate) AS lastsalary
    FROM gaps
)
SELECT *,
       FIRST_VALUE(lastsalary) OVER(PARTITION BY id, grp ORDER BY startdate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS lastsalary 
FROM cte 
ORDER BY startdate DESC
```

Comment: This is a really smart solution, but this problem could be considered as a gaps and islands problem when a salary value changes back to a previous value (*it could happen in the real world*). https://dbfiddle.uk/mADcWQuB

Comment: No, I didn't mean the gaps in the dates as the OP said, I mean the changes in salary itself could be gaps and islands.

Comment: Yes, just realized, was wondering if there's a quicker way to do that... the issue stems from partitioning on salary.

Comment: Yeah thought about that in first place when attempting to a solution. Overall it could be very niche to get an exact same previous salary, but agreeably can happen. I think you should add that answer to cover that case: yours is probably the best way to address that problem, that becomes effectively gaps-and-islands.

Comment: It's your idea :), you could update your post to cover that issue if it could happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple correlated subquery, with the inner select that looks back for the most recent different salary with the same id:

```
SELECT s.*,
    (SELECT salary
     FROM salaries s2
     WHERE s.id = s2.id AND s.enddate > s2.startdate AND s.salary <> s2.salary
     ORDER BY enddate DESC
     LIMIT 1) prevSalary
FROM salaries s;
```

| id | startdate | enddate | salary | prevSalary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-09-07 | 9999-12-31 | 19400 | 19200 |
| 1 | 2015-03-01 | 2015-09-06 | 19400 | 19200 |
| 1 | 2014-04-10 | 2015-02-28 | 19400 | 19200 |
| 1 | 2014-01-01 | 2014-04-09 | 19200 | 18000 |
| 1 | 2013-07-31 | 2013-12-31 | 18000 | NULL |

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that i'm using spark sql and I also added the mysql tag. Thats my bad. This solution is correct but would not work in spark sql as I cannot use correlated subquery like this. Again sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  current.employee_id,
  current.salary AS current_salary,
  previous.salary AS previous_salary
FROM
  employees current
LEFT JOIN
  employees previous ON previous.employee_id = current.employee_id
    AND previous.salary <> current.salary
    AND previous.hire_date < current.hire_date
WHERE
  current.salary IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  current.employee_id, current.hire_date DESC;
```